# Set custom postgresql.conf for one database on Mac using Postgres.app

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, configuration

I have ~20 PostgreSQL 14 databases on my local development machine running on Postgres.app.

I am trying to `pg_restore` a single 100GB database to Amazon RDS, but I'm getting some inconsistencies with errors such as:

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
Command was: CREATE INDEX ... ON public.... USING btree (..., ...);
```

I understand there are suggested settings that should make this process smoother (see [source 1: Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html) and [source 2: Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41402728/341583)).

Postgres.app seems to have a single `postgresql.conf` file for all my databases. How can I change these settings so they only impact the one database that's being uploaded?

Comment: I should think your first concern would be looking into the database server's log file to figure out what the underlying problem is.